# Defining a Mongoose Schema on the fly

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I have a model file that gathers together all my Mongoose models. One of the models I would like to initialize with a variable number of fields. Currently I'm defining more fields than I think I am going to require:

```
TallySchema = new mongoose.Schema
  0: Number
  1: Number
  ...
  20: Number
```

Obviously this is not ideal. I see Mongoose will let you specify options outside the Schema definition but can't see how to add new fields (or paths, I guess, in Mongoose).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the [mongoose plugin documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html) it looks like you can just do:

```
schema.add({ field: Number })
```

Answer (score 3):

This would need to be verified, but looking at the source it should be possible:

In the Schema constructor, it simply passes the definition object to `this.add()` ([source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/2.1.4/lib/schema.js#L37)).

The actual paths then get created within `Schema.prototype.add` ([source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/2.1.4/lib/schema.js#L97)).

So, seems like all you would need to do is something like:

```
// not sure what this looks like in CoffeeScript
TallySchema.add({ /* new property definition here */ });
```

Comment: Hi! There is a less "hacky" way to accomplish this? I mean, Mongoose don't have a special datetype or something similar that can be used to declare conditional sub-Schemas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the [Mongoose documentation page](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-add):

```
var ToySchema = new Schema;
ToySchema.add({ name: 'string', color: 'string', price: 'number' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'mixed' type to encapsulate your values.  It wouldn't be possible to have them be at the top level though but it works great otherwise.

```
new mongoose.Schema({
  average: Number,
  countPerRating: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
});
```

This is an excerpt from a mapreduce schema.  I use the mixed type to store the number of times someone gives a certain rating, so we can say things like "10 1 star ratings, 45 4 star ratings", etc.

mixed type worked great for that.